# SQL Multiple-Dependency UPDATE ON, what's most efficient?

Tags: mysql, triggers, if-statement

I'm trying to make a trigger that updates a table, and here's some psuedo code:

```
IF db.table1.column5 = 1
  {UPDATE db.table5.column5 = 1;}
ELSE IF 
db.table2.column5 = 1
  {UPDATE db.table5.column5 = 1;}
ELSE IF
db.table3.column5 = 1
  {UPDATE db.table5.column5 = 1;}
ELSE IF 
db.table4.column5 = 1
  {UPDATE db.table5.column5 = 1;}
```

What would be the most efficient way to do that?  For example, should I just make a bunch of triggers, or should I use the OR keyword or ELSE IF, like above?  Could someone show me how the code is formed, please?  It's my first time doing this.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: @Flimzy Oh ... right sorry.  It's been like 6 days since I worked on it.  I updated it so it's correct.  They're just supposed to be generic.

Comment: Okay, so this 'db.table1' object is supposed to be a row from db.table1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements, any time `column5` is updated in table1 through table4, you want to update the corresponding row in table5 as well?

You will want to use multiple triggers for this, one on each of table1 through table4.

Comment: I think you understood it correctly.  Just to be clear, it's not an xor or anything special.  If any of the tables, 1-4, have a change of column5 from `0/"false"` to `1/true`, then table5.column5 should be set to true.  Basically, it's an adult filter.  If any of the content is adult content, the whole node is adult content.

Comment: Another option (which may be better or worse, depending on many implementation details I don't know) would be for table5.column5 not to exist... and to instead be a view that queries the other 4 tables at the time of SELECT.

Comment: Could you show me code?  This is what I have: `CREATE TRIGGER adult BEFORE INSERT ON table1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE table5
    SET column5 = table1.column5
    WHERE table5.id = table1.id;
END;`

Comment: I'm sorry, I have never created a trigger in MySQL. I switched to PostgreSQL after MySQL 3 (which didn't support triggers).

Comment: Aw.  That's alright.  I'll keep testing until I figure something out.  Thanks, again.